# Basics of implementing a file system

Tags: file, unix, directory, system, implementation

My current project for an operating systems course is to design and implement a basic file system. I've read the chapters in our book about file systems, but I'm lost on where to start. 
I know some of the structures needed (file control blocks, system-wide open file table, per-process open file table, r+w buffers, directory structure), and the operations I need to support (open, read, write, delete, create, close).

I've been provided with a 10MB 'drive' to implement the file system inside of. 
Any help with resources or direct answers will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here's a link to the assignment https://www.dropbox.com/s/971ec21u3yn62wz/Laboratory%20Project%204_5%20Creating%20a%20File%20System.pdf

Comment: This is not even 'not a real question'. It's simply 'not a question'. I'd suggest libfuse, but I'm not sure it is what you are after

Comment: Sorry, the reason I haven't posed a 'real question' is because I don't know exactly what I'm looking for. I've seen similar problems such as mine posed on this forum, but the responses are usually links like libfuse that provide an API. I've been given a large file to implement this file system, but when it comes to getting pseudocode and program structure, I don't know where to start.

Comment: How's you filesystem going to be driven? Who will request access and store objects in it? Must it be (subset) POSIX compliant? Is it supposed to be kernel mode?

Comment: The filesystem is entirely in user mode. The whole thing will be stored inside one file on my computer, this file will only be a file system in my logical view, to the actual OS it is just another file. As of now, only the current user (me) needs to access it. As for the POSIX compliant part, I don't know what this means and I assume it does not need to be so.

Comment: However, you should rephrase your contribution to preserve it from being closed.

Comment: @user1837165, you may be able to revive this with an edit. I notice your 'question' doesn't contain any question marks. Adding a specific question at the end would probably help.

Comment: Is there any way I could make my answer more acceptable?

Answer (score 6):

You've asked a very broad question. And it wasn't clear if you have to implement a real file system but now it looks like you need to implement a set of operations that that your prof defined.

You write:

> I know some of the structures needed (file control blocks, system-wide open file table, per-process open file table, r+w buffers, directory structure)

It seems to me you're focusing on the wrong things. These are the in-memory structures used by a real operating system to support efficient access to a file system.

- **file control blocks** - your version of this could be *very* simple
- **system-wide open file table** - you don't need this to support a single user
- **per-process open file table** - you only need one and it could be pretty simple.
- **r+w buffers** - this is a performance enhancement, not strictly required by the assignment and can be added later if desired.
- **directory structure** - ahh, now you're on to something.

I read the assignment's mention "directory structure" as referring to on-disk structure. And that's what you probably need to focus on. You're given a big block of storage and you need to hand out little pieces. So you're going to need to write a storage allocator. The hard part really is designing the on-disk structures. You'll have to track which blocks are free. Files can be deleted, so you'll wind up with holes. Two simple approaches are using a bit map or a list of continuous free spaces. Whichever approach you pick, they'll be some part of your code where you'll wish you picked the other.

You'll also need a structure to track names. When a user creates a file, he names it. To open the file later, he gives the same name. On-disk structures are required to support this. There are other meta-data as well: last modified date (your assignment specifically requires this), file size, location of data. You can use your allocator to get space to store your meta data.

It's common to have a fixed block at (or near) the beginning of your storage to hold configuration information and pointers to other storage needed to get your filesystem loaded.

For a good overview of Unix filesystem concepts, I can recommend "The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System" by Marshall Kirk McKusick and George V. Neville-Neil, Chapter 8 Local Filesystems.

[http://www.amazon.com/Design-Implementation-FreeBSD-Operating-System/dp/0201702452](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201702452)

Specifically these sub-chapters:

- 8.8. The Local Filestore
- 8.3. Naming
- 8.9. The Berkeley Fast Filesystem

This helps one to think separately about storage allocation and naming.

Your assignment page includes some great references. I've had a chance to look over [Practical File System Design](http://www.nobius.org/~dbg/), which the author has generously posted online. I can specifically recommend these chapters:

- Chapter 4 The Data Structures of BFS
- Chapter 6 Allocation Policies

Plus maybe:

- Appendix A File System Construction Kit

Maybe the problem you're having is the project seems large and overwhelming. It really helps to break it down into smaller parts. If you're still lost, start by implementing the the part you understand the best.

Let's get back to the specifics of your assignment. It mentions these filesystem constraints:

- Files can be up to **16384 bytes** in size
- The allocation units, or blocks on the disk are each **512 bytes**.
- Your total storage area is **2-10 MB**

Constraints in this context are not bad, the're good because they limit what you have to deal with and allow you to cut a few corners. (I'm not saying any more because figuring out the details is the point of your assignment.)

If you're still stuck, you could read the source code to a simple file system like FAT. Here's a pretty accessible description of FAT:

http://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html

(Also check out Wikipedia.)

Here's a link to a C implementation of FAT intended for embedded applications:

http://ultra-embedded.com/?fat_filelib

The source code is only about 5K lines.

Good luck.